# Get all month ranges in given date range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to implement a below scenario

I have two dates like below

```
declare @start DATE = '2011-05-21'
declare @end DATE = '2011-08-17'
```

My requirement is to generate a table like below based on these two dates

```
StartDate        EndDate
-------------------------
2011-05-21       2011-05-31
2011-06-01       2011-06-30
2011-07-01       2011-07-31
2011-08-01       2011-08-17
--------------------
```

I tried the below CTE which is not giving me the output as I wish.

```
;with months (date1,date2)
AS
(
    SELECT @start,eomonth(@start)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date1),eomonth(DATEADD(month,1,date1))
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date2)<=@end
)
select * from months
```

Its producing these data

```
2011-05-21  2011-05-31
2011-06-21  2011-06-30
2011-07-21  2011-07-31
```

So could you please help me to tweak it

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use some conditions  in `select`

- StartDate: If `date1` is equal to `@start` it might choose `@start` otherwise you can try to use `DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(date1 ,-1))` to get the first day of the month.
- EndDate: If `date2` is greater than `@end` choose `@end` otherwise get `date2`.

The script as below

```
;with months (date1,date2)
AS
(
    SELECT @start,eomonth(@start)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date1),eomonth(DATEADD(month,1,date1))
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date1)<=eomonth(@end)
)
select IIF(date1 = @start,@start,DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(date1 ,-1))) StartDate,
       IIF(date2 > @end,@end,date2) EndDate
from months
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d11eef2cb43d37a320c85e4172f56cae)

Comment: +1 I had started [something quite similar](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=a07a89504633121c002d3349183f36ff).